# curl json with python to php

Tags: python, php, json, curl

i got problems in sending a json over curl to php. from php to php it justs works fine...

client side (python):

```
def sendAlivePing():
value = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
if(debug=="true"):
    print"alive ping: ",value
try:
    #update
    import requests
    url = 'xxx/xchange_server.php'
    payload = {'operation':'update',
          'service':'ip',
          'data':{'sqltable':'xxx',
          'default_ip':'xxx',
          'vpn_ip':'xxx',
          'name':'xxx'
          }}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print r
except:
    pass
```

Debugging information:

The response should be a string from a test echo.

on client side:

```
print r.content
print r.raw
print r.url
print r.headers.get('content-type')
print r
```

Result on client side:

```
NULL

<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0xb5d5a310>

xxxx.php

text/html

<Response [200]>
```

It seems my json goes not through the curl or not in the correct format....

My curl data which works in php:

```
// API URL
$url = 'xxx/xchange_server.php';

// Create a new cURL resource
$curl = curl_init($url);

// Setup request to send json via POST
//**EXAMPLE** IP Update
$data = array(
    'operation' => 'update',
    'service' => 'ip',
    'data' => array(
      'sqltable' => 'xxx',
      'default_ip' => 'xxx',
      'vpn_ip' => 'xxx',
      'name' => 'xxx'
    ),
);
    // Attach encoded JSON string to the POST fields
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

// Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

// Return response instead of outputting
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Set the CURLOPT_POST option to true for POST request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// Execute cURL request and getting response
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Close cURL resource
curl_close($curl);

// Display response
//echo htmlentities($response);

//load response into variables
$values = explode(' ', $response);
//var_dump($values);
echo $values[0];
//echo $values[1];

echo PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried passing the data as a JSON string instead of a dictionary into the request?

```py
import json
# your code
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```